# Can we add AND/OR between multiple rules, while using jQuery QueryBuilder ? library without using Group

Tags: jquery, query-builder, rules

I have a use case like

rule1 -----AND
rule2 -----OR
rule3 -----AND
rule4 -----OR
rule5

But I don't see a way to do this, it might be done using groups, But as a user I want to keep adding rules and specifying the condition between new and existing set of rules

We are not stopping the target user to do any precedence sorting and then add, just let them add

So the interpretation of our use case is like 
(rule1 AND rule2) OR (rule3 AND rule4) OR rule5. which is the default behavior of operator precedence.

Comment: did you find a way to do that?

Comment: No, I build my own custom code for achieving that